# Babel adding unnecessary core-js polyfills for IE11

Tags: javascript, import, babeljs, polyfills, core-js

In my app, I have configured Babel to add Core-JS polyfills, but it seems to be adding unnecessary polyfills.

Im using `browserlist > 1%` and it's including `require("core-js/modules/es.array.concat");` among other Core-JS imports that don't seem necessary.
I checked and it's because of IE11, but IE11 does support string concatenation with `+`, so this import doesn't seem necessary.

Is there a way to not allow adding these polyfills while still supporting at least IE11?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using preset-env [you can exclude](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#exclude) them directly with an array of excluded modules.

```
    ...

    "targets" : "browserlist > 1%",
    "exclude": [
        "es.array.concat",
    ],

    ...
```